# For non-citizen Nexus holder (Canadian PR), worth getting GE only for TSA Pre?

Tags: tsa, global-entry, nexus

I have Canadian Permanent Residency (PR) and obtained Nexus membership a couple years ago. Although I've been enjoying the benefits, I don't receive the full benefit as a non-US/non-Canadian citizen and do not get TSA PreCheck. I travel to the US multiple times a year for work and personal reasons, and I've been frustrated with airport security.

Global Entry eligibility has recently become available for citizens of my country, and I've been contemplating whether I should apply for it solely to gain access to TSA PreCheck. Fortunately, my credit card covers the Nexus/Global Entry application expenses, so I believe I would obtain it for free (or with some expenses covered). However, going through the application process again is a bit of a hassle.

What are your thoughts on holding both Global Entry and Nexus memberships just to access TSA PreCheck? Do you think it's worth it?

Comment: I don't think you need to - you should be able to qualify under the nexus program, as nexus and global entry are basically the same program. It may be possible to get TSA Pre activated on your existing account

Comment: @Midavalo Canadian PRs do not obtain TSA Pre with Nexus.

Comment: @Midavalo what xngtng said. the biggest difference I wasn't aware of, is that Nexus doesn't provide TSA Pre if you're not a US/Canadian citizen. something, not many websites provide clarity. I thought "may get TSA Pre" means you get TSAPre if the country of citizen provides GE, but I'm told that's not the case...

Comment: @user2669043 Interesting (and frustrating).  From my reading yesterday it appears you can "upgrade" your Global Entry (once you get it) to allow for use in Nexus lanes into Canada (you can already use it for travel into US), so maybe you won't need to hold both cards?

Comment: @Midavalo, would you happen to have the link to the document you were reading? I already have Nexus, so my "upgrade" would be to be the other way around, and I'm not even able to click on the GE with my nexus email...

Comment: @user2669043 [Global Entry Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/frequently-asked-questions) - The section I was reading was "Global Entry Frequently Asked Questions" > How do I add NEXUS to my existing Global Entry membership?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you think it's worth it?

YES!

That's obviously opinion based but I'm a big fan. Regular security lines are difficult to predict: sometimes it's empty sometimes but sometimes it winds through half of the terminal.

I don't think I have ever spend more than 5 minutes in a TSAPre line. Even if its longish, it moves fast since. You don't have to unpack anything, all your stuff (devices, liquids) can stay in the bag as packed.

So I think you can go to the airport half an hour later with TSAPre.

The cost seems very reasonable: $100/5 years.

The major downside is the application process: The application is not the easiest one and you have to go a specific location of an interview. There also seems to be a HUGE backlog at the moment. I renewed mine in last December and haven't heard anything back and mine has technically expired by now. Fortunately the government has instantiated a 1 year grace period for expired Global Entry

I suggest applying as soon as possible: it may take you a year to two to actually get it.

Comment: thanks! now I'm having trouble applying for GE with the same email account... looks like I'm gonna have to give them a call